# I modified /config/environments/development.rb, do I need to restart Apache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

In Ruby on Rails, I need to change SMTP settings in `/config/environments/development.rb`. 
After making the changes is it required to restart apache or any ather service?
Actually the mail is not getting still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Passenger you should just

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

on your app root.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-deploy your application.

Comment: i'm a beginner in ROR application. can you tell me how i re-deploy the application?

Comment: how do you start your application server ? and what server do u use webrick or thin or some thing else ?

Comment: How do u start the server in it.Do  you press the play button ?